# How to make python function use values from dictionary based on environment variables?

Tags: python, appium, pytest, python-appium

I'm automating testing on iOS & Android devices with pytest and Appium. 
Consider the following:

```
some_locator: 
       {
        'iOS': ('MobileBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID', 'some_id'),
        'Android': ('MobileBy.ID', 'another_id')
        }

def foo():
    bar = driver.find_element(some_locator)
    return bar.text
```

I want to run the script with either `'ios'` or `'android'` parameter from the command line to make function `find_element` use the corresponding tuple values. 
Also I know that I can do like this:

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--platform", default="ios")

@pytest.fixture
def cmdopt(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--platform")

# some_file.py

some_locator: 
       {
        'iOS': ('MobileBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID', 'some_id'),
        'Android': ('MobileBy.ID', 'another_id')
        }

def foo(platform):
    if platform == 'ios':
        bar = find_element(*some_locator['ios'])
    elif platform == 'android':
        bar = find_element(*some_locator['android'])
    return bar.text
```

but frankly speaking, I don't like it that way, because I'll have to add these `if` blocks in every method. 
Is there any convenient way to do it? My python is bad so I can't figure out the solution, please advice.

Comment: You can write your code like this  e.g.:

def foo(platform):
  bar = find_element(*some_locator[platform]) return bar.text. Make sure you handle the KeyError exception wisely .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use the `platform` variable to index `some_locator` directly? i.e.

```
def foo(platform):
    return find_element(*some_locator[platform]).text
```

Effectively the `some_locator` dictionary does the same job as the `if-elif` chain.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joe!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `platform` variable directly

```
def foo(platform):
    bar = find_element(*some_locator[platform])
    return bar.text
```

Comment: So obviuos! Thanks, don't know why I didn't figure it out myself

Comment: @NikBarch because once you stare at your own code for too long, obvious things are missed, happens to me all the time. Take a break, come back to it, and you'll see much more.